# Javascript: Async nested function in other async function gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, nested

I have two asynchronous functions the one nested in the other like this:

```
  //Async 1
  document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
     for (var i in event){
        //Async 2
        setTimeout(function(){
           console.log(i);
        }, 200*i);
     }
  });
```

What I want is to be able and print each entry(`i`) of the `event` object. The output on Firefox is however this:

```
MOZ_SOURCE_KEYBOARD
MOZ_SOURCE_KEYBOARD
MOZ_SOURCE_KEYBOARD
MOZ_SOURCE_KEYBOARD
..
```

If I move `console.log(i)` outside *Async 2* then I get the correct result:

```
type
target
currentTarget
eventPhase
bubbles
cancelable
..
```

Why doesn't it work correctly when reading the `i` inside *async 2*? Shouldn't `event` be "alive" inside the whole *Async 2* block of code as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var count = 1;
    for (var i in event){
        //Async 2
        setTimeout((function(i){
            return function () {
                console.log(i);
            };
        })(i), 200 * count++);
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/AQykp/

I'm not exactly sure what you were going for with `200*i`, since `i` is a string (not even digits). But I tried to fix it with `counter` in my answer, assuming what you really wanted.

So the reason you were seeing the results you were was because of the common closure problem. The `setTimeout` callback will execute after the `for` loop completes, leaving `i` as the last key in `event`. In order to overcome that, you have to add a closure that captures the value of `i` at that point in the loop.

Comment: The actual problem has to do with google maps so I tryied to simplify the problem and by accident "200*i" slipped through. Is there some resource that explains this any further?

Comment: Maybe this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem . The point is that the `setTimeout` executes asynchronously, later. By the time it executes, the synchronous `for` loop has already completed. Since the `setTimeout` references `i`, it is the last item in `event`. In order to capture it, you have to use a closure. Just Google "Javascript closure" to learn more about them, if the link I provided isn't enough

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout uses i as it appears in async1. That is, it references i instead of using the value of i when the timeout function is created. When your timeout function finally runs, it looks at the current value of i, which is the last key in `event` after the for-loop.

You can avoid this by using a self-calling function, such that the arguments of that function are local to the timeout function:

```
for (var i in event) {
    setTimeout((function(i) {
        return function() { console.log(i); }
    })(i), 200 * i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Event is indeed alive inside your callback.
The problem is that, by the time your function is executed, the value of i has changed (from what I can see from the output, the loop has ended and i has reached its maximum value) and thus outputting the same value for every callback.

If you use the function Ian commented, you will curry the actual value into a new function. That way the value of i can vary, you captured the current value inside the inner function